# Woeusb don't showing in applications Debian 10 Gnome

Tags: debian-buster

I am installed woeusb along this instruction https://github.com/slacka/WoeUSB.

```
git clone https://github.com/slacka/WoeUSB.git
./setup-development-environment.bash
sudo apt-get install devscripts equivs gdebi-core
mk-build-deps
sudo gdebi woeusb-build-deps_3.3.1-1-g7171bff_all.deb
```

This program didn't showing in applications, search don't finded it.Then i am installed from snap, don't finded too. What's a problem?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. You might try asking on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), or [Super User](https://superuser.com/) instead.